# How do I determine if an argument is an object or a built in?

Tags: python, types, dictionary, copy

How do I determine if a "variable" is builtin like string, list, dict or number and not an "object". I am trying to do a deepcopy-ish function for dicts which copies builtin types but ignores objects.

Comment: Everything in python is an object. You could use type(object) to determine the type of the object.

Comment: @AnkurAnkan the question is asking how to check for a buil-in, not for a pre determined type

Comment: @jamylak I believe @Ankur Ankan was just leading up to the use of `type(object)`.

Comment: Note that 99% of the time, you *don't* want to type-check. In Python, duck typing is the standard, so just use things, and catch exceptions if they fail. Never using type-checking to check for capability, as you will exclude types that act like another.

Comment: @Lattyware, I know, but in this case I saw no other simple way to do it. I have a dict I want to log in a database, but I am only interesting in things which can be JSON encoded as plain text. I have in the same dict some callbacks and stuff which I don't want to serialize. I don't want to remove them by name with `del`, because I don't want to modify the original `dict'.

Comment: @Prof.Falken Why not make your own [`JSONEncoder`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) subclass that ignores anything that can't be handled normally?

Answer (score 3):

Everything is an object. If you want to figure out if a certain object is a string or an integer, or another type, use [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
>>> isinstance("hello!", str)
True
>>> isinstance("hello!", int)
False
```

So, in your case, it seems you want to call a function only with dictionaries:

```
>>> mylist = [3, "cabbage", 5.43, {'cat':'dog'}, {'horse':'elephant'}, ['another', 'list']]
>>> for i in mylist:
...     if isinstance(i, dict):
...         dostuff()
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there are few built-in types, you can check using if:

```
if type(a)==int or type(a)==float or type(a)==str or type(a)==list or type(a)==dict:
        #do something
```

or use `isinstance()`

```
if isinstance(a,(int,float,str,list,dict,set)):
    #do something
```

Don't know if this is the correct way to do it. But it is one of the ways to check if the given variable is an instance of any built-in data type

Comment: `isinstance()` is cleaner :)

Comment: you could also do type(3)==int or type(3)==float

Comment: `if any(isinstance(a, t) for t in (int, float, str, list, ...)` looks more pythonic to me...

Comment: `isinstance` also takes tuples as second arguments, so `isinstance(a, (int, float, ...))` would work as well

Comment: @Volatility: yours was fine. So edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think using the `class.__module__` attribute, which holds the module *name* where the class was defined, is the best way to go:

```
>>> import __builtin__
>>> int.__module__ == __builtin__.__name__
True
```

Notice that although the builtin module is automatically imported, we have to import it to bring it in scope and fetch its name.

For a user defined class:

```
>>> class A: pass
...
>>> A.__module__
'__main__'
```

Comment: Seriously, I don't get how to use this.

Comment: `def is_builtin(obj): return type(obj).__module__ == __builtin__.__name__`

Answer (score 1):

First of all everything is object, so I suppose you want to test for built-in types versus user defined types.

Pick the built-in's that you want to exclude and compare [type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type)() of the variable.

```
if type(yourvar) in [list,set,int,float,str,dict]:
    print "builtin"
else:
    print "object"
```

In general [isinstance](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) is preferred to comparing [type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type). However isinstance will be True for objects that extend built-in types:

```
>>> class A(list):
    pass

>>> a = A()
>>> isinstance(a,list)
True
```

Therefore if you want strictly built-in types, you shouldn't use isinstance.

Comment: Don't forget about bool! I was using this, and I needed to add that for my code to work. :)

Answer (score 0):

**CPython** only approach (may work in other implementations as well):

```
import __builtin__

builtin_types = [x for x in __builtin__.__dict__.values() if isinstance(x, type)]
def is_builtin_type(x):
  for t in builtin_types:
    if isinstance(x, t):
       return True
```

This covers built-in exceptions, bytearrays, objects, and couple others, that guys on other answers did not mention :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in Python there is no difference between classes and types:

```
>>> type("234"), "234".__class__
(str, str)
```

Then testing a type for an objects can have two different meanings:

`isinstance` tests if your object is of a given type or a subtype:

```
>>> class mystr(str): pass
>>> s = mystr(4)
>>> s
'4'
>>> ype(s)
__main__.mystr
>>> isinstance(s, str)
True
```

whereas

```
>>> type(s) is str
False
>>> type(s)
<class '__main__.mystr'>
```

by the way you shouldn't write `type(s) == str` but `type(s) is str`.

Now a possible answer to your question: the module of a builtin type is `__builtin__`

```
>>> str.__module__
'__builtin__'
>>> mystr.__module__
'__main__'
```

So you probably can write

```
>>> def is_of_builtin_type(obj):
        return type(obj).__module__ == '__builtin__'
>>> is_of_builtin_type("4223")
True
>>> class mystr(str): pass
>>> is_of_builtin_type(mystr(223))
False
```

Note: I haven't tested how robust this is.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I went with this solution: (inspired by [this](http://writeonly.wordpress.com/2009/05/07/deepcopy-is-a-pig-for-simple-data/))

```
from six import integer_types, string_types, text_type

_copyable_types = (
    integer_types,
    string_types,
    text_type,
    list,
    dict,
    set,
)


def deepish_copy(org):
    '''
    Will copy a dict but ignore user objects at top level.
    '''
    out = {}

    for k, v in org.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, _copyable_types):
            try:
                out[k] = v.copy()   # dicts, sets
            except AttributeError:
                try:
                    out[k] = v[:]   # lists, tuples, strings, unicode
                except TypeError:
                    out[k] = v      # ints

    return out
```

Answer (score -2):

**Straightforward**

For a given variable `var`, using the function `isinstance(var, type)` returns `True` if `var` is of type `type` and `False` otherwise. You can check this easily in the interpreter:

```
>>> a = 2
>>> isinstance(a, int)
True
>>> b = 'correct'
>>> isinstance(b, int)
False
>>> c = [1,2,3,4]
>>> isinstance(c, list)
True
```

...and so on. So if you want to check that `item` is a `dict`:

```
if isinstance(item, dict):
    # handle the dict, do your deep copy
else:
    # meh, whatever
```

**Alternatively**

Consider using the [types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html?highlight=types#types) module which allows:

```
from types import DictType
def dictate(item):
    if isinstance(item, dict):
       # handle the dict
    else:
       # panic!
```

Comment: @Prof.Falken: refer my answer for a good explanation

Comment: Heh @AswinMurugesh I was just going to refer him to yours anyway.

Comment: Checking `type(var)` is a terrible idea that doesn't allow for subclassing.

Comment: Thanks, @Lattyware. I've replaced it with isinstance().